# Fedora 29 can't connect to httpd

Tags: apache-2.4, fedora

I'm trying to spin up a dev instance on RackNerd and can't connect via http by IP or domain name. I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT via browser rather than any specific errors. I've configured Apache on many other servers, but I'm missing something, most likely obvious, in this instance.

I did try setting up the one vhost, but even before that I was getting a time out error and no Apache config page.

I can ping the server by IP address.

I can ping the server by the one vhost domain name I have pointing at it.

I can connect via SSH by IP address.

I can connect via FTP by domain name and IP address.

BUT I cannot reach it via http in the browser.

httpd is running, restarts without issues, and passes configtest

[Httpd config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0yhF.png)

IPTables is not installed. firewall-cmd shows http already enabled.

[Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7j4g.png)

Ports appear to be open.

[Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJWyK.png)

It sure feels like a firewall is blocking ports 80 and 443, but I have no idea from where - I don't see anything like that in the RackNerd control panel (this is an ultra-discount service so there is no support included). If there is a firewall, why would 20 and 22 be wide open and 80 and 443 locked down?

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want fedora 29?

Comment: It was one of the most up-to-date RPM-based packages on RackNerd. I'm going to look at what else is available as my next plan.

Comment: The prod version will be deployed on Amazon Linux, so I prefer working in the RH family.

Comment: Fedora 29 isform 2018. It's Ancient

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

firewall-cmd --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --add-port=443/tcp

Comment: Firstly, Fedora 29 has been EOL since November 26th of 2020. Secondly, that command is not going to take effect and persisnt reboot unless you add the `--permanent` flag and then run `firewall-cmd --reload`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight into --permanent!